# JsonObject has some extra character

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I m using Volley library in android to get JsonObject from my server.

i have create the proper json in server with php

but when i get the json from server it occur a weird problem

[image]

i m using json_encode in php to produce json

i dont know what are these extra characters in front of json?

do you know how to solve this problem???

this is a error that i got in android

07-18 20:40:49.151: W/System.err(11636): com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value ï»? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

thanks in advance

Comment: that's a UTF BOM. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8

Comment: please tell how to solve this problem. where should i set this encoding?

Comment: is it a problem from server or from mobile application?

Comment: If you're on Android, why don't you just use the libraries included within the SDK? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: @jaytj95: what makes you think the OP is not? the exception `org.json.JSONException` suggest they are, which is consistent with the fact that Volley does use the library included in the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted this as a comment but I wanted to post the relevant code that is in the link. If it works, awesome, if not let me know and I will remove this (as I haven't tested it).

From [Skip BOM](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18508)

"The problem is that your UTF-8 string starts with a byte order mark character (BOM) '0xfeff'. We should fix our JSON parsers to skip this character if it exists.

As a workaround, you can use this code to strip the BOM when you go from InputStream to Reader."

```
public Reader inputStreamToReader(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    in.mark(3);
    int byte1 = in.read();
    int byte2 = in.read();
    if (byte1 == 0xFF && byte2 == 0xFE) {
      return new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-16LE");
    } else if (byte1 == 0xFF && byte2 == 0xFF) {
      return new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-16BE");
    } else {
      int byte3 = in.read();
      if (byte1 == 0xEF && byte2 == 0xBB && byte3 == 0xBF) {
        return new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8");
      } else {
        in.reset();
        return new InputStreamReader(in);
      }
    }
  }
```

"Or you can remove the byte order mark from your file!"